# onPostExecute does not get called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Activity (RecipiesActivity) that is opened by clicking on the "Next" button of the Main Activitiy of my application.

In the RecipiesActivity onCreate, I want to call a webservice in an AsyncTask. For now, since I have not implemented the webservice yet, I am just calling a webservice provided by bitly (but this is irrelevant to my problem).

The problem is that although the webservice gets called and no exception is thrown, a result is return from the doInBackground, but my onPostExecute is not called. I have done some research and I have found the possible reasons as listed below - but none seem to be my case:

- onPostExecute parameters do not match the AsyncTask parameters - in my case they match
- A bug in android that does not allow the AsyncTask to be executed in the UI thread. It is supposadely overcomes by using Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask") - I tried this and did not make any difference
- AsyncTask is not started from the UI thread - in my case I believe it is
- doInBackground does not return - in my case it does, I have stepped through it with the debugger
- @Override is not used before onPostExecute - in my case I am using @Override

The code is below:

```
public class RecipiesActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipies); 
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Response);

        //Start the WS call in an AsyncTask 
        new CallWS().doInBackground("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=maskedLogin&apiKey=maskedKey&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F");          
    }

    private class CallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String result = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
            HttpGet get_request = new HttpGet(params[0]); 
            try
            {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get_request, localContext);
                //int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    InputStream istream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

                    try
                    {
                        result = br.readLine();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //TODO Handle the IOException that the readline may throw 
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        istream.close();
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                //TODO Handle the IOException and the ClientProtocolException that the 
                // httpClient.execute can throw
            }
            finally
            {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
            return result;
        } 

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                tv.setText("The result is NULL");
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setText(result);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Your help is appreceiated,

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `doInBackground()`, simply call the `execute()` method of the AsyncTask. Calling `doInBackground()` does what it says on the tin: calls `doInBackground()` (in the same thread) and returns. It won't call `onPostExecute()` for you. `execute()` will start a background thread, call `doInBackground()` on the background thread, then post the result of `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. This (obvious) mistake has caused the problem.

Comment: I was going to do so right after it was posted, but it required me to wait for about 7-10 mins before doing so. Anyway, answer is marked now :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line

```
new CallWS().doInBackground("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=maskedLogin&apiKey=maskedKey&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F");
```

to

```
new CallWS().execute("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=maskedLogin&apiKey=maskedKey&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the obvious and silly mistake done. I would mark this as an answer too, but unfortunatelly, I can only mark one.

Comment: Never mind, glad it worked, however you can upvote the comment if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your onPostExecute function has @Override